# JavaScript Rounding not working

Tags: javascript, html, rounding

I am trying to create javascript code that rounds a number to the nearest integer, tenths, hundredths, and thousandths place, but it is not working. Can you see any reasons why?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Rounding</title>
<head>
<script  type="text/javascript">

    var roundToInteger(x);
    var roundToTenths(x);
    var roundToHundredths(x);
    var roundToThousandths(x);

    x = window.prompt("Enter a integer");

    function roundToInteger()
    {
    x = Math.round(x);
    }

    function roundToTenths()
    {
    x = Math.round(x * 10 + .5) / 10;
    }

    function roundToHundredths()
    {
    x  = Math.round(x * 100 + .5) / 100;
    }

    function roundToThousandths()
    {
    x = Math.round(x * 1000 + .5) / 1000;
    }

    document.writeln ("<h1>""x" Rounded to a integer is + roundToInteger() + "<h1>");
    document.writeln ("<h1>""x" Rounded to the tenths place is + roundToTenths() + "<h1>");
    document.writeln ("<h1>""x" Rounded to the hundredths place is + roundToHundredths() + "                   <h1>");
    document.writeln ("<h1>""x" Rounded to the thousandths place is + roundToThousandths() + "<h1>");
</script>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're doing the operations in the wrong order. The first thing you do is throw away the fractional part by rounding to an integer value. Also, your `document.writeln()` calls are syntactically incorrect and should be generating errors you can see in the developer console.

Comment: `It not working` does not explain much. Can you elaborate ? The `window.prompt` returns an string. You need to parse that as float or integer.`x = parseFloat(window.prompt("Enter a integer"));`

Comment: Why are you passing arguments (`roundToHundredths(x)`) if you don't use them? (`function roundToHundredths() {}`)

Comment: These are the two errors in my console: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string Ex.11.4pt2.html:29 &
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT

Comment: 1 - Your functions don't return anything. 2 - `x` is a string (returned by `window.prompt`) that you're trying to round. 3 - your `document.writeln` lines aren't valid syntax, and are not invoking your functions. 4 - Your math is wrong - you should divide first if you want to drop precision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read more javascript. Your code is full of errors. Your `<script>` should be on `<body>`, as you write on the page (on the body). Also, then you write `<h1>` you have to close it on the end `</h1>`. The `<title>` should be inside `<head>`.

Anyway, read the way i modified your code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>The page title is inside head</title>
        <script>
            // Here you can declare your functions
            function roundToInteger(value)
            {
                var new_value = Math.round(value);
                return new_value;
            }
            function roundToTenths(value)
            {
                var new_value = Math.round(value * 10 + .5) / 10;
                return new_value;
            }
            function roundToHundredths(value)
            {
                var new_value = Math.round(value * 100 + .5) / 100;
                return new_value;
            }
            function roundToThousandths(value)
            {
                var new_value = Math.round(value * 1000 + .5) / 1000;
                return new_value;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            // Make a pop up box
            var x = window.prompt("Enter a number"); // Lets say you enter 1.623425
            // Use console.log to print errors on the console. (F12>Console)
            console.log('You entered', x);

            document.writeln("<h1>\"x\" Rounded to a integer is " + roundToInteger(x) + "</h1>");
            document.writeln("<h1>\"x\" Rounded to the tenths place is " + roundToTenths(x) + "</h1>");
            document.writeln("<h1>\"x\" Rounded to the hundredths place is " + roundToHundredths(x) + "</h1>");
            document.writeln("<h1>\"x\" Rounded to the thousandths place is " + roundToThousandths(x) + "</h1>");
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you I have read your comment and made the proper adjustments and it now works. I guess I have a lot more to understand about what I have read.

Comment: Practice make us better. Also every time open the console and look you any javascript error.

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen functions written that way before. Are you sure that's not the problem?

Try writing your functions this way:

```js
// Set up variables
var x, y;
// Set up function
var gimmeTwo = function(a) {
  a = Math.round(a) + 2;
  return a;
};

// Obtain and clean input
x = window.prompt("Enter a integer");
x = parseInt(x);

// Runthrough function
y = gimmeTwo(x);

// write out
document.write(x + " gimmeTwo is " + y);
```